# How to select the Values using Keys from a single JSON row

Tags: mysql, json

My JSON TABLE is as below

I have a table called **jsontable** which has a JSON column with the following content :

```json
[
  {
    "username": "adam",
    "password": "123"
  },
  {
    "username": "alex",
    "password": "1234"
  },
  {
    "username": "john",
    "password": "1235"
  }
]
```

I want to select the data as below as

```
SELECT username, password FROM jsontable
```

returning the result below

| username | password |
| --- | --- |
| adam | 123 |
| alex | 1234 |
| john | 1235 |

I do know how to select from a single dictionary i.e.

```
SELECT JSON->>'$.username',
       JSON->>'$.password'
  FROM jsontable;
```

But I do know how to select from a list of dictionaries. Kindly help!!!

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan 
Thank you for the reply :) . Can you please pass me a pseudo code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_TABLE()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) function provided that the version of the DB is 8.0+ such as

```
SELECT username, password
  FROM `jsontable` AS j
  JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                 `json`,
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (
                                 username VARCHAR(100) PATH '$.username',
                                 password INT          PATH '$.password' 
                               )
       ) jt
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/irCoZntG)</kbd>